# Conditional PM Notification

Tags: members, email

Is there a way to send a member PM notification only if that member is not logged in the site?When the member is on the site, I show a growl notification to that member whenever that member receives a PM. In that case, there is no need to also notify the member via email. I'd like the PM notification email to only send when the member is not logged in. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had used [Messaging](http://www.intoeetive.com/docs/messaging.html) addon much before and think it can work for you. Basically your main goal is "not to send PM email notification to member if logged in". Right? This addon is having a hook `messaging_pm_sent` by using which a small extension can be developed just return if member is logged in (no PM notification will be sent) or just a little hack can be put there.

I hope, it would help you.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used this, but it seems to have high reviews. Maybe you should try a plugin like :

http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/mx-notify-control

Otherwise I do not believe there is a way to anything like that natively in EE.